# Understanding how to convert char[0] to int

Tags: c++, string, char, int

I was trying to go in a loop and each time convert a character in a string to it's integer value and I don't mean the ASCII value. Tried to use atoi() with no luck but then I stumbled upon this question [Convert single char to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800875/convert-single-char-to-int) and my code worked. The code is as follows:

```
std::string tmp = "87532621";
for(i=0;i<tmp.length();i++)
  {
     **int num = tmp[i] - '0';**
     //do some processing
  }
```

I fail to understand why the following line of code works. My question is how is it converting the char value to integer type?

```
int num = tmp[i] - '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Each char in your string is an ascii value. The ascii values are just 7 bit numbers.
The numerical values for the character digits lies in a sequence *0123456789* which is very convenient because it makes it possible to write

```
int zero = '0' - '0'; // 0 (zilch)
int one = '1' - '0'; // one (1)
int nine = '9' - '0'; // 9 (three times three)
```

And so on.

The actual numerical values are not important for this to work. The fact that the are next to each other in the character set is.

See wikipedia - ascii for the actual numerical values.

Comment: "0...one...9" Either spell it all out or use all numerical characters. This is killing me.

Comment: @Josh, You should see a doctor about that. I like zilch, I think the Lucky Luke comic had a zilch whiskey in it.